# allow extra properties in webapi model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, serialization, asp.net-web-api2

How do I configure webapi to allow extra properties, which are not in the model and should be ignored? Currently the serialization fail it there are additional properties, but missing (non required) properties work. We need this to make the api more robust.

Example for model in webapi:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

But we send this to the contract:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string IAmExtra  { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: this question lacks important context. please take some time to write a good question if you expect good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have solved this now by making the model type to an open type accordingly to this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/use-open-types-in-odata-v4

Like this

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

Now we can accept the extra properties without serialization issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use mapper to map from webapi Dtomodel to your model:
/[Using Automapper in ASP.NET Core project](https://dotnetthoughts.net/using-automapper-in-aspnet-core-project/)

Comment: I added example. We already use automapper after receiving. The problem is that the receiving model is not matching what the clients send in.